# Sources for information about Danish general government finances since 2000 (in English)

Tags: government-debt, public-economics, fiscal-policy, government-spending

for a report I have to write about Danish public finances and fiscal policy (budget balance, debt, revenues, expenditures) I'd like detailed information dating back to 2000 or publications giving an comprehensive overview of the recent history. In English since I don't understand Danish. I've already found Statistics Denmark, yet the [statistics](https://www.statbank.dk/statbank5a/selectvarval/define.asp?PLanguage=1&subword=tabsel&MainTable=OFF3B&PXSId=202607&tablestyle=&ST=SD&buttons=0) it provides for general government expenditure and revenues only date back to 2015. I'm curious to see if there's something with a more expansive time-range. The Danish ministry of finances also offers [publications](https://en.fm.dk/publications/?year=2010) that should help me along the way. However, I'm still interested in finding other, hopefully more comprehensive, sources of information.

Help much appreciated, regards.

Comment: Try to see what you can find at the Danish national bank. https://nationalbanken.statistikbank.dk/statbank5a/default.asp?w=1843

Answer (score 1):

The [IMF Fiscal Monitor](https://data.imf.org/?sk=061a17b2-7e6a-4b58-9b17-042af9e59a3d&sId=1409151544549) is generally a very good source for the information you're looking for. Simply select 'by country' and search for Denmark. Their database contains the indicators you mention in terms of GDP and dating back to 1993.